# What's the name of the part between the fingertip and hyponychium?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

What's the name of the part between the fingertip and hyponychium?

I want to describe some kind of feeling there. I know I can say the phrase "This feeling is in between the fingertip and the hyponychium", but I'm looking for the term for this place. I googled for my question but I found nothing about it what I'm looking for.

In this illustration, the area I'm looking for is noted with the letter **e** (the photo was taken from [this](https://archive.org/details/comparativeanato00neal/page/172/mode/2up) book, but this letter notes it for other purposes).

[image]

Comment: I'd call it the *finger tip*. But you apparently think the finger tip is somewhere else. What part are you calling the finger tip?

Comment: What I understand it's called fingertip, is shown on the diagram was attached by @Astralbee. It's a little bit lower to where I'm asking about. The place between the fingertip and nail is the place I'm looking for.

Comment: That area is apparently called the hyponychium, although I'll admit to not knowing that term until reading your question.

Comment: The fingertip isn't a single point, it's the whole surface of the finger, from the last joint to the edge of the nail.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Anyway, check my answer bellow, I found the accurate term. It isn't hyponychium (which basically means 'under the nail'), because hyponychium is very close to the nail. See here: https://i0.wp.com/post.healthline.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/1.jpg?w=1155

Answer (score 3):

The area marked 'e' on your diagram *is* what most people would call the "fingertip".

"Fingertip" is not really a medical term so there is no specific limits to the area it refers to. It literally means the tip of your finger. I would say that the surface area of the top of your finger, where you have a fingerprint, is your fingertip. This anatomical diagram agrees.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most of the people will call it **fingertip**, even though it isn't specific. Anyway medical professionals that want to be more specific will call it **distal pulp**. But it isn't a common term in spoken English. So If the purpose is spoken English, it's better to use the *fingertip*, but if the purpose is medical English, then the *distal pulp* is the accurate term.

For reference and more information - see [here](https://meeting.handsurgery.org/abstracts/2016/P44.cgi).

[image]

Comment: *Distal* basically just means "further away from the spine", if I recall correctly. And proximal means "closer to the spine". Colloquially you could say something like "the tip of the fingertip" or "the fingertip just below the nail".